# Github OAuth : The remote server returned an error (403) Forbidden

Tags: c#, http, github, oauth, get

I've managed to receive the `access_token`, browsing to `https://api.github.com/user?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE` works very well and the browser displays all my information.

But when I'm trying to get these information with ASP.NET (C#), I get an error:

> The remote server returned an error (403) Forbidden.

Here is the code I'm using to make an Get Request.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.github.com/user?access_token=" + access_token);
request.Method = "GET";
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse(); //Error Here
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Is there a redirect that you haven't accounted for?

Comment: @ZachSpencer The Redirect URL of the Github App is probably only used when I'm requesting the `code`, I did that using C#, then I've requested the `ACCESS TOKEN`, both procedures were using `POST` as Github says. Retrieving user info is done through GET, this is when I get the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I monitored the request and response in my Firefox when I directly access the URL (which works). I had to set the right content type. I added the following and everything worked.

```
request.UserAgent = "Foo";
request.Accept = "application/json";
```